# Split up bootstrap 3 typeahead search

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, search, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on implementing a search autofill and they have been using bootstrap typeahead for almost all their autofill functions. The problem with the one I'm currently working on is it doesn't spit out the correct info.

Basically, bootstrap prints out the sku and then the product info into a search row (eg. 18238 EB 25 Edge Bander), and then will search this. When the code searches this though, it looks for a title that matches exactly that, with the sku, which doesn't exist. If I search just "18238" or just "EB 25 Edge Bander", I get the correct results, but they want the search suggestions to show both the sku and the title.

I'm wondering if there's a way to either split the bootstrap search into two, like if it's numbers go by sku and if it's letters go by title, or if there's a way to have it display both as options but only search one or the other (display 18238 EB 25 Edge Bander and search for 18238)?